# Как отфильтровать вывод в cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Задача: получить список вида имяфайла:md5хешсумма посредством .bat скрипта.
Я уже понял, что хеш-сумму можно получить с помощью встроенной утилиты certutil:

```
for %%f in (*) do (
certutil -hashfile "%%f" MD5
)
```

Но вывод у такого скрипта будет такого вида:

```
C:\Users\root\Desktop\important>(certutil -hashfile "Tracking.txt" MD5 )
Хэш MD5 Tracking.txt:
44e4006f20ad89584ed6a02c1c16f77b
CertUtil: -hashfile — команда успешно выполнена.

C:\Users\root\Desktop\important>(certutil -hashfile "tuta.txt" MD5 )
Хэш MD5 tuta.txt:
74b2317ab4a05beb8fe3f6410a183b0a
CertUtil: -hashfile — команда успешно выполнена.
```

Подскажите, как мне выдернуть конкретно хеш из такого вывода, а в идеале что-бы вывод был такого вида:

```
Tracking.txt:44e4006f20ad89584ed6a02c1c16f77b
tuta.txt:74b2317ab4a05beb8fe3f6410a183b0a
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой вариант. Выводим 1 и 2 строки.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (*) do (

set /a count=1 
for /f "tokens=*" %%t in ('CertUtil -hashfile %%f MD5') do (
  if !count! equ 1 echo %%t
  if !count! equ 2 echo %%t
  set/a count+=1
)

)
```